# jsf inheritance abstract class

Tags: jsp, jsf, inheritance

In my project I have a @Entity abstract class EVENT. I have few @Entity classes extends EVENT, like LOGIN, CHANGE_NAME, SEND_TEXT. Each class has it's own fields - Login has fields from EVENT plus ip, CHANGE_NAME has field with old username, SEND_TEXT has field with text itself,plus who you send text.
Now - I have an @Entity with @OneToMany relation to Event class.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "wycenioneAuta", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    private Set<Event> event= new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

It stores all Event performed on this @Entity. Now I describe my problem:
I want to display history of events. I tried

```
<ui:repeat value="class.event var="e">
 #{e.id},
 #{e.date}, 
 #{e.user.name}
 </ui:repeat>
```

but I can only display field from concrete class, whenever I try to get data from specific event, my application crush, 'couse f.e. Change_name does not have the field 'ip' or Send_Text does not have field oldUsername. Is there a way to display those data? When I debug my app, the set of Events looks good - every event has it's field filled correctly.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I needed to do something so here's how I solved this problem:
I made few @Transient methods in concrete class. They looked like this:

```
@Transient
public boolean isChangeName(){
   return (this instanceof ChangeName);
}
```

and in my page:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{entry.eventList}" var="e">
     #{e.isChangeName? e.oldName: ""}
     #{e.isSendText? e.text: ""}
</ui:repeat>
```

it works just like I wanted - shows a list of events with details.
Hope it helps someone someday:)